# How do I run multiple SQL Queries using "if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){"

Tags: php

Trying to make a CRUD, everything works except my Update function. I feel like the problem is in the second sql query. When I click on submit it just refreshes and the change is gone. Can anyone show me how to find what I need to change/show me what to change?

```
    <head>
<title>Update</title>
</head>

<body>
</form>



<?php 

require_once('dbconnect.php');
$id =  $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dealers where ID=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<form action="" method="post">';
        echo "Company: <input type=\"text\" name=\"CName\" value=\"".$row['CName']."\"></input>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Contact: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Contact\" value=\"".$row['Contact']."\"></input>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "City: <input type=\"text\" name=\"City\" value=\"".$row['City']."\"></input>"; 
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<input type=\"Submit\" = \"Submit\" type = \"Submit\" id = \"Submit\" value = \"Submit\">";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$sql = "UPDATE dealers SET CName='$CName', Contact='$Contact', City='$City' where ID=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL-Injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Please start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: If you have no choice (I had a PHB that insisted that any HTML was served via PHP `echo`) -- then in your `if(isset($_POST)` logic block. You need to re-execute `SELECT * FROM dealers where ID=$id  --> and echo back the HTML for the changes.` Since this is server side logic serving up HTML it's messy as a pig in mud. You need to separate your concerns: You have a SELECT (cRud) and an UPDATE (crUd) in the same function. This is bad, even if you are serving up dynamic HTML from the server (which is also bad).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building a form inside `PHP`, just break with ending PHP tag inside your `while` loop and write your HTML in a clean way then start PHP again. So you don't make any mistake.

Also you've to submit your `$id` from your form too.

Try this

```
<?php 

require_once('dbconnect.php');

$id =  $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dealers where ID=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

    <form action="" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>" />

        Company: <input type="text" name="CName" value="<?= $row['CName'] ?>" />
        <br>

        Contact: <input type="text" name="Contact" value="<?= $row['Contact'] ?>" />
        <br>

        City: <input type="text" name="City" value="<?= $row['City'] ?>" /> 
        <br>

        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

<?php

    } // end while loop

    echo "</table>";
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

**Note:** You are passing undefined variables into your update query. As you are submitting your form you must have to define those variables before you use them.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $CName     =   $_POST['CName'];
    $Contact   =   $_POST['Contact'];
    $City      =   $_POST['City'];

    $id        =   $_POST['id'];

    $sql = "UPDATE dealers SET CName='$CName', Contact='$Contact', City='$City' where ID=$id";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Your answer is more full.

Answer (score 0):

that loop? ID primary key or not?

maybe u need create more key in table dealer like as_id

```
<input type="hidden" name="idform" value="$as_id">
```

in statment

```
if($_POST){
$idf = $_POST['idform'];
if(!empty($idf)){
$sql = "UPDATE dealers SET CName='$CName', Contact='$Contact', City='$City' where as_id=$idf";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
}
$conn->close();
}
```